# User gets downvotes on answer, delete it, then reposts it exactly as is

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136829/java-inputstream-from-url-cannot-resolve-the-host), the user [YCF_L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5558072/ycf-l) posted an answer which was downvoted twice for two reasons:

1. there was no resource control, possibly leaving the disk in an uncertain state.
2. it didn't actually answered the question (why does the `UnknownHostException` occurs)

Then the user deleted his answer.

But after a few minutes, he posted the exact same answer and was *again* downvoted, the only change to the previous answer is him writing

> I don't know why some guy downvoted my question.

I downvoted again because none of the issues were solved.

Then the user deleted the answer again, but posted a comment before doing so (I know, because the page was left open and I can still (barely) read the comment):

> so is that why what you want from me, did you see mee in your dreams or what @OlivierGrégoire ok i will delete my answer again, but this is really stupid action you do

I personally believe this behavior shows that the user has no idea of how SO works. Deleting a downvoted answer is good. Reposting it exactly as it is hoping no one will downvote is bad, imo. This behavior makes me think YCF_L is only there for rep. I hope I'm wrong.

What can I do? What should I have done? Who can do anything?

Comment: the answers are both deleted, what exactly do you want to happen here?

Comment: @RobertLongson , my guess is that he properly wants a mod to talk to / and or investigate mentioned user about down votes and how SO works, albeit I'm not sure if making a metal post is the correct way of doing so

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile This site needs quality content and not a bunch of bad answers kept as a reminder. When you know why you've got downvoted and see the issue with the post, then either improve it or delete it.

Comment: @Tom there are answers that just get downvotes and no comments, that what I mean, above, stick around maybe someone will point why u got DV, but when u just delete u might never knw

Comment: @RobertLongson there were several issues at hand: first the user added an answer that had nothing to do with the question. Second, when people reacted negatively to that, the user deleted the answer (nice!) but reposted it exactly as is (not nice!), it's like purging the history of bad rep. Third, the user acts as if he didn't get any feedback (see my first quote, him using the comments system shows he knows he got feedback).

Comment: Fourth, the user acts as if reposting the (bad) answer is totally the normal way to go (see my second quote). His deletion aren't "I did something bad" but "others didn't like it, but they should have liked it". My questions are indeed what are my options for this scenario. There are possibilities in the "duplicate" topic, so thank you for that.

Comment: Yes, but what outcome do you want that you haven't already had i.e. that the answers are deleted.

Comment: @RobertLongson The user is a 6k rep user. I think that he should have somehow learned. At 6k I believe you should be able to acknowledge that an answer is incorrect and not reposting it, and even after that not bitching about the fact that you had to delete it again. And I don't count about the lying ("I got no feedback"), yet 2 users gave him feedback, and me on each answer.

Comment: What do you propose to do to make that happen? Do you want that Stack Overflow send people round to his house and make him, or something else. I'm trying to get to what action you want here?

Comment: @RobertLongson Please read my post. I asked what I can do. This very clearly implies that I see next to zero options here and I'm asking the community about some. If the community says there are none, I'm a grown man, I can accept that. If you want to go to that user's house, be my guest, just don't overstate what I said or asked.

Comment: In situations like this, when you have < 10k rep and can't see the user's deleted answers it's OK to flag the question asking a moderator to investigate. Someone else has flagged the answers now.

Comment: I've personally flagged this behavior from this same user twice in the past. I hope you're being more stern in your messages to them, @bolt and team.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: Yeah, I know.